# Populating tableView inside a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I am trying to create a `UITableView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`. My goal is to implement a tableview inside my CollectionViewCell and populate my tableView with simple data. I want to create pages of tableViews populated with different categories of data.

I thought it would be a relative easy task, however I am getting a Threat 1: signal SIGABRT error. The debugger is prints

> ```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
> ```
>
> '-[TableViewMockUp.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b07cc0'

I am not sure what this error is telling me. When I look inside my ViewController I don't have a tableView numberOfRowsInSection method.

I have the project on Git if you want to take a look: https://github.com/cyrilivargarcia/TableViewMockUp

Below is a snapshot of my ViewController class
[image]

This is a snapshot of my CollectionViewClass which is where I created my TableViews.
[image]

Any idea on how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -[TableViewMockUp.ViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100b07cc0
>
> I am not sure what this error is telling me. When I look inside my
>   ViewController I don't have a tableView numberOfRowsInSection method.

You've hit the nail on the head. The error is telling you *"you don't have a numberOfRowsInSection method"*, and your reply is *"I don't have one"*.

So... you just need to add that method to your view controller :)

Edit: After reviewing your code, to clarify for your specific case...

You had your TableView Delegate and DataSource connected to the wrong thing.

- In IB, select your table view...
- In the Utilities pane, select the Show Connections Inspector
- Click the little "x" to delete the current Delegate and DataSource connections
- Drag to the CollectionCell in the Document Outline tree

That should do it!

Comment: That doesn't make sense though. I can't add that method because inside my ViewContoller, that is where my CollectionView methods are implemented. All the TableView methods are inside my CollectionViewCell class, and I have the numbersOfRowsInSection method in there.

Comment: Sorry - I should have taken a look at your code first... You had the Table View Delegate and DataSource set to your view controller. They need to be connected to CollectionCell - which is where the functions are.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried doing that, but it worked! Thank you for your time!